# Intellij doesn't deploy the good bytecode while I debug à WAR exploded

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-2, war

I have to work on an old project that uses Struts 1.x and Maven 2.2.1
 I've retrieved the source code from our SVN as an Intellij project and I can launch the web server (JBoss 4). 
My troubles are when I want to debug the code. I've got a « java code doesn't match with the bytecode ». I’ve followed the guide to configure an exploded artifact and I don't have any idea why I get this problem.

It's like Intellij isn't able to use the rigth compiled class files while debugging.

Does anyone know the solution ?